# Why don't my icons change in Unity?

Tags: 11.10, unity, themes, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appearance does not change on switching the theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73576/appearance-does-not-change-on-switching-the-theme)

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and it has been a headache ever since. I have gnome-tweak-tools installed, CCSM is configured to work well with Unity, and I have tried each the three built-in Unity themes.

My problem is that when I change the theme, only the window border changes. The icons don't change (on the panel and otherwise), Nautilus still looks ugly, scroll-bars don't change, etc. Everything looks very plain, boxy, and Windows 98-like. I didn't have any of these problems with Ubuntu 11.04 (of course I wasn't using Unity then).

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to a screenshot?

Comment: @JorgeCastro Possibly, but my desktop never even shows the theme, not even slightly. `sudo gnome-settings-daemon` results in changed icons (sometimes for awhile sometimes it ends immediately after closing terminal) but Nautilus and menus are still bad.

Comment: Well, certainly running g-s-d as sudo is going to make it worse, as now it's writing files in your home directory that your user account can't access.

Comment: Yes, but that was something that a user tried to do so I thought I might as well give it a go. The only thing the top-rated answer did for me was to lock up my touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

My answer to this exact same problem was to create a new user account and them move over none system files, then to carefully replace any . files.

The issue is caused by Nautilus or the setting daemon crashing during logon and then nautilus cannot ever get a path to the required theme.

There is a file in your user directory that is causing the problem.

Now that I have a working platform I'll do a trial and error search to see if I can find the offending file.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly because `gnome-settings-daemon` is not running.

Can you make sure that your have the latest version of this package. I can find this [old bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/395871) about it

Comment: I typed `gnome-settings-daemon` in a terminal and got this:** (gnome-settings-daemon:24877): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down. I tried `sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon` and was notified that I have the latest version.