# Appearance does not change on switching the theme

Tags: 11.10, unity, themes, lightdm

If I select Radiance or Ambiance in the menu show in the following picture, my whole theme does not change. It only changes the title bar.

How can I resolve this problem? Or how can I reset the theme to default?

Comment: What happens when you try to change the theme with the `ubuntu-tweak-tool`?

Comment: I tried it. But _nothing_ happens. I cannot see a change in the GUI.

Comment: I have this problem, too. It occurred after running a modified version of unity-greeter thus: `unity-greeter --test-mode`

Comment: This is related to lightdm, apparently.

Comment: why did you run unity-greeter?  Please add an image of your issue.  What were you trying to fix by running unity-greeter?  What happens after a reboot?

Comment: i just tried unity-greeter command to take the screenshot of login screen

Comment: Oh, this one.... heh. *writes an answer*

Comment: @Matthew Possibly. We'll see what tachyons says.

Comment: @Matthew yeah it is similar problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the file ~/.config/dconf/user solves the problem.

PS: To reconstruct the problem I made the following steps:
change in the file /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf the line

```
font-name=Ubuntu 11
```

to

```
font-name=Ubuntu 10
```

and after saving run the command

```
lightdm --test-mode
```

That was all I modified yesterday. Now if you restart your session with CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE and login again, your theme is ugly (like mine on the screen shot in my question). Can anyone verify this?

Comment: -1. Removing `~/.config` might solve this particular problem, but it'll cause others (most user settings will be lost). So, it's an unacceptable solution.

Comment: That's the way I didn't accept this as "the solution" for this question. So what's an acceptable solution, Scott Severance?

Comment: I wish I knew. I'm experiencing the same problem, for the same basic reason. I haven't found a solution, and am unwilling to delete `~/.config`

Comment: Then perhaps you should backup your ~/.config and delete every file in there step by step, so you find the files which are causing this bug.

Comment: @ScottSeverance I refined/edited my solution. Only remove ~/.config/dconf/user. Then many settings like Desktop background and so on are gone, too. But this is more fine than removing the whole ~/.config folder.

Comment: You're right. This change is better. I've removed my down vote. Since `~/.config/dconf/user` is a binary file, I can't manually inspect it for corruption. I have many custom dconf settings, so I don't like this solution, but I'm guessing that your suggestion is not only correct, but also the only solution. So I guess I'll have to bite the bullet.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. It turns out that more stuff lives in dconf than I thought. Grr. Anyway, +1 for this suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps anyone knows the option or the options in the dconf user file. So that you can edit it with the dconf-editor. But atm i have no motivation to find this needle in the haystack.

Comment: I'm thinking it's file corruption, because I've manually tweaked the theme settings in `dconf-editor` to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

Install dconf-editor if you don't have it, and then go to

> org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings

and check "active." One thing I've also noticed when this happens is that the media keys stop working: enable org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media keys. There also might be some more plugins you should enable.

Problem cause: when unity-greeter is run (by the lightdm --test-mode command in my case), it disables a lot of settings-daemon plugins that have to be manually reenabled.

I got all of my info from this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861476

Comment: A great answer! Helped me with a similar issue on 12.04 and finally I've got my media keys back! Very comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after I ran `unity-greeter` in the terminal. From that moment on my theme did not load completely anymore. Only the title bar could be changed by selecting another theme.

Deleting config files, logging out, `dconf-editor` settings and so on did not work for me.

What solved the problem was to run `/usr/bin/gnome-settings-daemon` in the terminal. All settings were instantly in place.

So, I added it to the 'startup items' and the problem was solved. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, here's what happened:

When you ran Unity Greeter, it started to really freak out, because its not supposed to be run as a normal user (although it is possible, I'll get into that in a moment).

To fix it, you need to go into dconf-editor (install the `dconf-tools` package), and then head to Org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins, and then make sure that everything is enabled.

Log out and back in and you should be good to go!

To run Unity Greeter/lightDM in a window so you can take screenshots, run

```
unity-greeter --test-mode
```

or

```
lightdm --test-mode
```

Comment: oh thanks i enabled Org > gnome > settings-daemon > plugins >xsettings ->active now it works :) without any logout

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried logging out/logging back in? Typically on my install the theme switch does not complete until I do this.

It is curious that some of your desktop seems to revert back to the default GNOME theme, though.

Also, if this does not work, you may also want to try a reboot.

Comment: Yes, I have tried login/logout. Several times. I was so distressed, that I rebooted.

Comment: @Strubbl That's all I can think of. Sorry if I was unable to help.

Comment: No problem. I am not giving up and keep this thread up to my latest insights.

Comment: Logging out doesn't work. Rebooting doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. After lots of search I came to know that gtk 3.4.2 was the root of the problem. I installed it for my programming purposes. Even the above solutions were not working in my system. So I just uninstalled it and it started working just fine.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu ,Don't ask question in answer section ,please post it separatly including link to this question :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem on Ubuntu 14.04.  I was unable to change my theme after restarting my computer.  I could hack around the issue by logging out and logging back in.  I noticed this problem shortly after installing Ubuntu and installing some programs and drivers.

Resetting unity solved the problem for me.  I used the unity-tweak-tool to do this as unity --reset is no longer allowed:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

**Edit** The problem is back, this did not fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
    gksudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop
```

and then replacing the line:

```
    Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
```

with:

```
    Exec=bash -c "sleep 5; /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon"
```

You might need to increase the sleep number.
I got this from webupd8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu 13.04. I just installed the [gnome-tweak-tool [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool) and changed the current theme under theme menu. It solved this.