# How can I change my Nautilus and icon themes back to what I had before?

Tags: nautilus, icons, themes, interface, gnome-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appearance does not change on switching the theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73576/appearance-does-not-change-on-switching-the-theme)

For some reason, from about a few days ago, windows and icons look like Linux circa 1995.

I tried resetting my theme to "Radiance", but it was already set to that.

I don't know why anything would suddenly look different in my themes or icon sets or anything. I haven't done anything to change my interface.

In any case, how do I get back the theme I had before? I think it was "human" or "gnome" or something like that. Nice orange folders and stuff.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? And what User Interface?

Comment: 11.10, gnome-classic with Compiz.

Comment: Does this help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/73576/appearance-does-not-change-on-switching-the-theme

Comment: @jokerdino: Yes, it did. Thanks! I think it was the second answer, to delete ~/.config/dfconf/user, and then re-logging in, that solved the problem. What do I do with this question, then? Mark it as duplicate or something?

Comment: Don't worry. I will just flag the question as dupe and the mods would deal with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you install gnome-tweak-tool:

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool

you can access more customization options, including the theme, by launching 'Advanced settings' or gnome-tweak-tool through a terminal. A good starting point would be to see if the original themes (ubuntu-mono-dark for icons, ambiance for window and gtk+) are still listed in this tool under 'Theme'.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. In gnome-tweak-tool, all the icon themes are there, but changing them has no effect on the style of icons I'm seeing. If I change the "Window theme" the changes take place immediately. The "Icon theme", currently set to "Humanity" looks nothing like Humanity. No matter what I change it to, it looks like this clunky decades old Linux style of icons.