# gtk theme became ugly

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appearance does not change on switching the theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73576/appearance-does-not-change-on-switching-the-theme)

I just run `unity-greeter` from terminal it worked without any problems but my theme changed to ugly default theme of gnome ,I tried to change it using ubuntu-tweak and gnome-tweak ,but it didnt work

[image]
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: this might be the same problem (http://askubuntu.com/questions/73576/appearance-does-not-change-on-switching-the-theme)