# Nautilus explorer looking weird

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appearance does not change on switching the theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73576/appearance-does-not-change-on-switching-the-theme)

My nautilus (file explorer) looks weird suddenly, even after a reboot.. Ubuntu 11.10

[image: Screenshot of how my nautilus looks]

Comment: Hi. It might help if you were to add more information to your post. For instance, did it happen suddenly and randomly, or did something possibly trigger it? Have you changed any system setti ngs recently that may have caused it? Are there problems other than the icons being weird? Are the icons like that on your desktop, too? On AskUbuntu, there is no such thing as too much info. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I just clicked the Home icon on the unity launcher. I guess it was because I had run an update-Manager before that. And it works fine now, although I have no idea why. It didnt work that time even on a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened nautilus with sudo (`sudo nautilus`)? It may have change the permissions of nautilus preferences to root. To fix that, run this (changing "user" for your user name):

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus
```

Comment: Thanks. But it wasn't sudo nautilus. Just clicked the Home icon on the unity launcher. I guess it was just because I had run an update-Manager before that. And it works fine now, although I have no idea why. It didnt work that time even on a reboot

Comment: I'm glad it is working now.